# Repetir animação em css

Tags: css, animação

Boa tarde.
Estou com um pequeno problema na animation do css.
Estou utilizando 3 keyframes diferentes para fazer uma animação, entretanto quando acabar esses 3 keyframes gostaria de repeti-los exatamente na mesma ordem.
Se coloco a propriedade a `animation-iteration-count` como `infinite` ele fica completamente louco.

Para entender melhor o que estou falando, veja o exemplo no link https://jsfiddle.net/4pnquy2p/1/

Assim que a palavra "Mirai" some, gostaria de repetir o efeito do começo.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Era bom copiar o seu código e color na pergunta. Assim pessoas com o mesmo problema podem ver o código se um dia o seu link deixar de funcionar. Veja a central de ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help e em especial esse guia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Filipe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atualmente o CSS animation não possui a propriedade delay após o fim da animação, a propriedade existe apenas ao iniciar a animação.

Entretanto, fazendo alguns cálculos simples, é possível fazer a animação se repetir utilizando apenas CSS.

Como não me limito apenas a colar códigos e quero que você entenda a solução proposta, a explicação ficará um pouco longa. Se você apenas que uma solução sem entende-la (não recomendo), basta copiar os códigos CSS que postei abaixo separadamente e substituir no seu atual código.

Veja o seu atual código CSS:

```
.anima-escrito {
    animation: draw 2.6s 0s forwards 1 linear, 
    preenche .5s 2.6s forwards 1 linear, 
    some .5s 3.6s forwards 1 linear;
}

@keyframes draw {
    to {
       stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes preenche {
    to {
        fill-opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes some {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Traduzindo para linguagem humana, o código acima diz que a animação `draw`irá ter 2.6 segundos de duração com um delay inicial de 0 segundos, a animação `preenche`terá uma duração de 0.5 segundos com um delay inicial de 2.6 segundos e por fim a animação `some`terá uma duração de 0.5 segundos e um delay inicial de 3.6 segundos.

Fazendo os cálculos, a duração total da animação será de 4.1 segundos.

A técnica que vamos utilizar é alterar a duração de todas as animações para que fiquem igual ao tempo total de toda a animação e a gestão do delay e do tempo da animação será feita dentro de cada animação, ou seja, dentro de cada `@keyframes`.

Na pártica iremos entender melhor.

Vamos alterar a classe `anima-escrito` para que todas as animações fiquem com 4.1 segundos de duração:

```
.anima-escrito {
    animation: draw 4.1s linear infinite, 
    preenche 4.1s linear infinite, 
    some 4.1s linear infinite;
}
```

Sabemos que a animação `draw` tem uma duração desejada de 2.6 segundos sem nenhum delay, então basta fazer uma regra de 3 simples, ou seja, se a animação total e de 4.1 segundos e a animação `draw` é de 2.6 segundos, basta fazer o cálculo 2.6s*100/4.1s = 63%. O resultado indica que a animação `draw` irá ocupar 63% do tempo total.

```
@keyframes draw {
    63% {stroke-dashoffset: 0;} //63% representa 2.6 segundos de 4.1 segundos, ou seja, a animação irá durar 2.6 segundos.
    100% {stroke-dashoffset: 0;} //de 63% a 100% (ou seja, 1.5 segundos) mantemos sem nenhuma alteração.
}
```

Para a animação `preenche` é necessário fazer mais 1 cálculo, uma vez que existe um delay na animação. A animação tem um delay de 2.6 segundos, ou seja, ocupa 2.6s*100/4.1s = 63% da animação total e o tempo desejado da animação é de 0.5 segundos, ou seja, ocupa 0.5s*100/4.1s = 12% da animação total.

```
@keyframes preenche {
    63% { fill-opacity: 0; } //durante 2.6 segundos nada é alterado
    75% { fill-opacity: 1; } //durante 0.5 segundos (75-63=12%) alteramos a propriedade fill-opacidade de 0 para 1. 
    100% { fill-opacity: 1; } //de 75% a 100% (ou seja, 1 segundo) mantemos sem nenhuma alteração.
}
```

O mesmo ocorre para a animação `some`. Sabemos que ela tem uma duração de 0.5 segundos e um delay de 3.6 segundos.

```
@keyframes some {
    87% { opacity: 1; } //durante 3.6 segundos nada é alterado
    99% { opacity: 0; } //durante 0.5 segundos (87-99=12%) alteramos a propriedade fill-opacidade de 0 para 1
    100% { opacity: 0; } //de 99% a 100% (ou seja, 0.041 segundo) mantemos sem nenhuma alteração. Podemos eliminar a linha onde diz 99% uma vez que 0.041 segundo é imperceptível aos olhos humanos.
}
```

Veja [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/4pnquy2p/3/) o código a funcionar.

Comment: Filipe, sua técnica funcionou bem para essa única animação.
O problema é que eu tenho uma outra parte dela, que não coloquei na pergunta, pois achei que teria uma forma que, se eu soubesse resolver a primeira, também resolveria a segunda.

Entre a primeira animação (o escrito Mirai) e a segunda (O logo) deve existir uma pausa, que é o tempo do logo aparecer e sumir.. 
Estou tendo dificuldades de aplicar esse seu conceito entre as duas transições.

Segue como é a animação completa:

https://jsfiddle.net/5ba2chwd/1/

Comment: @guidezin é a mesma técnica aplicada acima, penso que você não entendeu o conceito. Ao entender o conceito você irá conseguir alterar conforme a sua necessidade.

Comment: @guidezin veja aqui um exemplo aplicando o conceito acima com 2 logotipos: https://jsfiddle.net/5ba2chwd/4/

Comment: Obrigado, vou estudar esse exemplo com os 2 logotipos para ver se entendo melhor.

Comment: @guidezin o link que enviei acima tem 2 animações, as 2 devem ter o mesmo tempo de duração, a primeira inicia logo e para até que o tempo total passe, a segunda fica parada e começa quando a primeira acaba sua animação, simulando um delay.

Comment: Filipe, agora eu entendi melhor a lógica. Entretanto estou com um problema que não consigo resolver (problema esse que não é mostrado no Jsfiddle), mas no Chrome e no Firefox sim. 
Quando a animação acaba, antes de começar novamente, os dois elementos aparecem (apenas pisca, dura alguns milesegundos), e desaparecem de novo.
Sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: @guidezin a resposta que dei resolve o problema proposto, você tem todo direito de voltar na sua decisão mas quando essa não responde a sua questão inicial ou quando passa a existir uma resposta melhor. Isso é um outro problema que não tem a ver com a pergunta, se não daqui a pouco temos uma resposta que nada tem a ver com a pergunta. Você não precisa marcar a minha resposta como certa, mas se surgiram outras duvidas que são diferentes da pergunta original, abra um outro tópico. Quando ao problema, estou tentando perceber qual a razão.

Comment: @guidezin nas classes "anima-escrito" e "anima-bola" basta adicionar a propriedade `opacity: 0;`. Se quiser que funcione em outros browsers (IE8, safari) veja aqui como fazer o cross browser: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/ .

Comment: Obrigado Filipe. Tive que adicionar um código em javascript para alterar as opacidades no fim e no começo da animação pois se eu coloco opacity:0 na classe ele resolve o problema, mas não fica com o efeito desejado.

Answer (score -4):

Depois de muito tempo vou deixar uma resposta para qm deve estar iniciando  e tem uma duvida parecida ou a mesma.
Se vc colocar um pouco de javascript puro deve funcionar de forma bem simples e eficiente,
crie uma constante com o valor em milisegundos
ex:
const time = 60000;
"time" corresponde a 1 minuto(60000 milesegundos)
e crie uma classe no objeto que deseja animar e repetir a animaçao a cada 1 minuto,
vou usar de exemplo a nome "anima" para a classe.
use setInterval() para fazer funcionar,
ex:
setInterval( ()=>{
anima.classList.toggle("anima");
}, time);
a cada "time"(60000ms), troca a classe do objeto para "anima" e o retira nomavente no mesmo intervalo, assim repetindo a animação.